# Why does window.onload event occur before $(document).ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload, document-ready

As stated in this thread: [window.onload vs $(document).ready()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready). The `window.onload` should occur later than the `$(document).ready()` but in this simple code the log would show that the `onload` event is executed before the ready event? What I'm I missing here?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>A Simple Site</h1>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      console.log("ready event fired");
    })
     window.onload = function() {
      console.log("onload event fired");
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have no content in the page which affects the load event (ie. external CSS or imagery) therefore the `load` event fires almost instantly. I would imagine it fires before jQuery's document.ready event due to the inherent overhead with jQuery. If you add an `img` to your HTML, then the ready handler fires first - as is your expected behaviour.

Comment: @BharatPatidar that's the question the OP linked to in their question which states that the behaviour should be the opposite of what the OP is getting - which is the whole point of this question

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes right, agree with your first comment

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I just tried to add different images to the code. It seems i have to add certain amount of images for the onload event to occur later which seems strange to me. Since even if its only one image, the onload event would have to wait longer for that image to be loaded and therefore occurs later.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is not with the order of the events. It with the jQuery wrapper around the native DOM events. If you try the native `DOMContentLoaded` you will find that it always runs before `window.onload`. But the jQuery event
`$(document).ready` will come some milliseconds after `DOMContentLoaded`, which in some cases might be after `window.onload` too, especially if the page doesn't have much to load like the code below. This is delay is due to jQuery implementation.

If you uncomment the iframe in the code though, it takes some time to load which causes the `window.onload` to be delayed, so `$(document).ready` will come first.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>A Simple Site</h1>
    <!-- <iframe src="http://stackoverflow.com"></iframe> -->
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            console.log("jQuery ready");
        })
        
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
            console.log("DOM ready");
        });
        
        window.onload = function() {
            console.log("DOM loaded");
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a "feature" of jQuery 3. jQuery 1.X has **always** handled $(document).ready before $(window).on('load'). Furthermore, $(window).load() can be considered as an event when page is rendered. I'm 100% certain in this because now I just had an attempt to upgrade jQuery version to 3.X in a project that's been working stable with jQuery 1.X for almost 10 years. So this attempt has turned into a month of headache struggling with $(document).ready and $(window).load. Finally it was decided to leave it with jQuery 1.12.4, the latest of 1.X generation.

Answer (score 1):

@RoryMcCrossan saying is right, you have nothing in your `html` to be load on `window` like(image,video etc ). Now you can see how behavior of event is changed

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <img src="http://www.wallpapereast.com/static/images/Unique-And-Beautiful-Wallpaper-HD.jpg" alt="Alternate Text" />

  
</head>

<body>
  <h1>A Simple Site</h1>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      console.log("ready event fired");
    })
     window.onload = function() {
      console.log("onload event fired");
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I just tried out your code. If I were to load only the first image, the behavior is still not as expected. Do you have some explanation for this?

Comment: @HoangVu now you can see there is only one image and `onload` event is firing after `ready`, you can understand what i mean. image size was smaller so it wasn't took more time then time needed to `DOM` to be ready

Comment: @BharatPatridar I can see that the size/amount of the images matter but does that mean the `onload` event doesn't need to wait for the `DOM` to be fully loaded or does the `ready` event waits for something more than `onload` without the images?

Comment: if there is nothing like (css ,images) then `onload` doesn't care for `DOM` to ready and `DOM` does not wait for image to be fully loaded

Comment: Sorry but I dont think that is correct since the `DOM` is always ready before the page is fully loaded [link](https://api.jquery.com/ready/). The `DOMContentLoaded` event also always fires before the `onload` event regarless of the presence of images. Therefore my conclusion is that jQuery's `$(document).ready` does not only waits for the `DOM` to be ready but also something else. And when exactly jQuery's `ready` event is fired relatively to `window.onload` still remains my question.